# Python - Slider for X axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slider

I am performing a data analysis in Python. My data is huge and when plotted, it is so messy to see. So I am trying to use X axis slider, so that, an user can slide over the x axis and visualize it easily .

I tried the following code :

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,7))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)



Trial = ax1.plot(x,y,'.', color='blue',markersize=1,label='B1')

axpos = plt.axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03])
spos = Slider(axpos, 'Time', matplotlib.dates.date2num(2022,1,28), matplotlib.dates.date2num(2022,4,12))

def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    ax1.axis([matplotlib.dates.date2num(pos), matplotlib.dates.date2num(pos)+relativedelta(months = 1),80,100])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

spos.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

And I got this output as in figure
[image]

I don't know what mistake I am doing. I want a figure where I want to have X axis for one month and then slide it for next month. For example if my start date is 2022,1,28, I want to view it until 2022,2,28 at once and then use the slider to view it for next month. Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

here, but you have to replace x and y with your data :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as wg

@wg.interact(this=wg.FloatSlider(min=1, max=10, step=0.5, layout=wg.Layout(width="500px")))
def run(this):
    
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

    # x and y must be your data
    x= np.linspace(-5,5,1000) 
    y= np.sin(x)                       

    Trial = ax1.plot(x,y,'.', color='blue',markersize=1,label='B1')

    def update(val):
        pos = this
        ax1.axis([matplotlib.dates.date2num(pos), matplotlib.dates.date2num(pos)+relativedelta(months = 1),80,100])

    ax1.set_xlim(-this, this)
```

[image]